# How do I deploy web2py on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: python, web2py, pythonanywhere

How do i get a basic web2py server up and running on
[PythonAnywhere](http://www.pythonanywhere.com)?

Comment: getting the admin site running is an extra challenge, because HTTPS isn't supported yet - I've included a workaround in my answer...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[update - 29/05]  We now have a big button on the web tab that will do all this stuff for you.  Just click where it says *Web2Py*, fill in your admin password, and you're good to go.

Here's the old stuff for historical interest...

I'm a PythonAnywhere developer.  We're not massive web2py experts (yet?) but I've managed to get web2py up and running like this:

First download and unpack web2py:

```
wget http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/web2py_src.zip
unzip web2py_src.zip
```

Go to the PythonAnywhere "Web" panel and edit your `wsgi.py`. Add these lines:

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/my_username/web2py'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

from wsgihandler import application
```

replacing `my_username` with your username.

You will also need to **comment out the last two lines** in wsgi.py, where we have the default hello world web.py application...

```
# comment out these two lines if you want to use another framework
#app = web.application(urls, globals())
#application = app.wsgifunc()
```

Thanks to Juan Martinez for his instructions on this part, which you can view here:
http://web2py.pythonanywhere.com/

then open a *Bash* console, and `cd` into the main `web2py` folder, then run

```
python web2py.py --port=80
```

enter admin password

press ctrl-c

(this will generate the `parameters_80.py` config file)

then go to your *Web* panel on PythonAnywhere, click **reload web app**,
and things should work!

Comment: There is no `app = web.application(urls, globals())`

Answer (score 4):

You can also simply run this bash script:

http://pastebin.com/zcA5A89k

admin will be disabled because of no HTTPS unless you bypass it as in the previous post. It will create a security vulnerability.

Comment: Pls explain `python -c "from gluon.main import save_password; save_password(raw_input('admin  password: '),433)"`

Answer (score 2):

Pastebin was down, I retrieved this from the cache.

```
cd ~
wget -O web2py_srz.zip http://web2py.com/examples/static/web2py_src.zip
unzip web2py_src.zip
echo "
PATH = '/home/"`whoami`"/web2py'
import os
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr
os.chdir(PATH)
if not './' in sys.path[:1]: sys.path.insert(0,'./')
from gluon.main import wsgibase as application
" > /var/www/wsgi.py
cd web2py
python -c "from gluon.main import save_password; save_password(raw_input('admin  password: '),433)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently summarized my experience with deployment of Web2Py on PythonAnywhere [here](http://www.icd10doc.com/init/recipes/DeployWeb2PyPythonAnywhere)

Hope it helps
NeoToren

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to add something new to the discussion. The EASIEST way I've found is to go here when you aren't logged in. This makes it so you don't have to mess around with the terminal:

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-web2py

Come up with a domain name, then you'll get redirected to a page showing your login information and created dashboard for that domain. From there just create an account so your app isn't erased after 24 hours. When you sign up, your app has a 3 month expiry date (if you're not paying). I believe this is a new policy. Then simply go to https://appname.pythonanywhere.com/admin and then enter the password you were given and then upload your Web2Py file into the dashboard and then visit the page.

I'm not sure how to upload a Web2Py app on PythonAnywhere for an existing account, but that's the easiest method I've found.

Comment: PythonAnywhere dev here: just to clarify one point -- free accounts keep their web apps forever, but you have to log in and click a button at least once every three months to keep them running.  That's to stop our servers from getting clogged up with sites that people set up to try something out but don't want any more.  We're happy to keep hosting your site indefinitely if you actually want it :-)