# How do I deploy web2py on PythonAnywhere but from Dropbox shared folder?

Tags: python, dropbox, web2py, pythonanywhere

I have tried to use this link 
  [How do I deploy web2py on PythonAnywhere?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386240/how-do-i-deploy-web2py-on-pythonanywhere)
to deploy Web2py on Pythonanywhere but from Dropbox's shared folder.

```
path = '/home/my_username/Dropbox/web2py'
```

The result is ...

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request
```

.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at your error logs?  (in `/var/log/apache/error.log`, you can access these via the **Web** tab).  You may find you have an `ImportError`, because a package you depend on isn't available on PythonAnywhere.

Most packages can be installed by doing a

```
pip install --user package_name
```

You then also need to add the following directory to your `sys.path` (in addition to the web2py folder):

```
/home/my_username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

[update] - this question was cross-posted to the PythonAnywhere forums, where we continued to debug the issue.   the final solution was to do with **Dropbox permissions**

http://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/9/

The answer was to

```
chmod g+w /home/Lazarof/Dropbox/web2py
```

Because the Dropbox folder has special permissions on pythonanywhere, our dropbox sync client needs group-read-access permissions to work.

Comment: All the package are in place and the error is [Wed Dec 07 10:23:07 2011]   File "/home/Lazarof/Dropbox/web2py/gluon/main.py", line 68, in <module>
[Wed Dec 07 10:23:07 2011]     create_missing_folders()
[Wed Dec 07 10:23:07 2011]   File "/home/Lazarof/Dropbox/web2py/gluon/admin.py", line 439, in create_missing_folders
[Wed Dec 07 10:23:07 2011]     os.mkdir(path)
[Wed Dec 07 10:23:07 2011] OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/Lazarof/Dropbox/web2py/deposit'